# Python: Is there any way I can take a script and import it's contents to idle in order to edit them there?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-import

I have a little a script containing some "dictionaries".

"Is there any way I can take this script and import it's contents to idle?"* using a command like **import**.

What  want to do then is to edit (or view) these dictionaries "live" in idle.....

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. What do you mean you have a script that contains dictionaries? What do you mean *view them live*. Given that you are a beginner and the right lingo might not be obvious, you should probably elaborate as much as possible, to communicate your exact intent clearly.

Comment: Can you not simply open the file for editing from the Idle command line or menu?  How do the tutorials show you to open a file?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I believe this is called _text-editing_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have to confess that I use linux mint, so there's no such thing as idle and that is why I use the terminal (where I type **python3**) to code instead! To make it clear, what I wanted to do is to take a script which contains a dictionary and some functions and then run it in terminal in order to use those functions there. The **import** command has nothing to do here!!!The answer is to use the **exec** commmand!!! Here is a picture:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljyff.png). My question was not clear......
P.S Mushroommaula answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste the script into the shell. Make sure there are no blank lines inside indented blocks or you'll get a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, import command should work: Just put "import myScript". You can add a path to your script with a line like sys.path.append(r"D:\myPath") before that statement

Comment: Probably need to add a mention of `reload` or restarting the script before importing again.

Comment: True,you can reload it by imp.reload(myScript), you will have to import imp too (import imp, imp.reload(myScript))

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows right click on the script > Open with > Choose your Idle if it's there if not click on more(not sure what it's named it's the last option) then there should be some more options to open the file if your idle is still not there you can browse your files and go to the folder where your idle is saved and choose the exe to open the script in the Idle